# SP2013 - Possible to do a count of items in a Person/Group field?

Tags: 2013, list-view

I have this custom list (Meetings) with a Person/Group field (Meeting With). 
I have a web part view (Team Meetings) of this list that should show where

> count(Meeting With) > 2

Currently it only shows when there are 5 people (x AND y AND z etc.) in the filter. 
I need it to show whenever there is any permutation of those 5 people where the count of individuals is > 2.

Any way to do that out-of-the-box or with Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: how is it done by now? What kind of webpart is it?

Comment: @user1901384 The web part currently only shows Meetings where Meeting With = A AND B AND C AND D AND E. So it only shows Meetings when it's been scheduled with those specific 5 people. I want it to show when it's any permutation of A, B, C, D, and E whenever there's more than 2 people involved.

Comment: is it a listview webpart?

Comment: @user1901384 Yep, just a standard OOTB custom list web part.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the view of your List View WebPart in the Webpart Settings and set the filter  to: 
Show items only when following is true -> Person contains "A" OR Person contains "B"....

You can add more statements by clicking on "show more columns". Does this work for you?
If there would be a meeting with 1 person only, it would show up anyways. Is this bad or is there no szenario where only one person is in a meeting?

Comment: If I use ORs, it does not satisfy the count(Meeting With) > 2. It would show items that would only have a single person in it as well.

Comment: an ugly solution would be to just add a hidden column with a personcount to your table (formula = COUNT(PERSON) or something) and then add a last filter with and personcount > 2.

Comment: Thought about that already. The data type, People/Group, does not work with formulas. At least, I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: hm seems to be more tricky than I thought. It seems that you can't use People Picker in Calculated Columns. The problem with doing it by jquery/javascript is that you probably loose the ootb functionalities like opening the list item from the webpart. If you don't need this I could provide you a solution in Jquery.

Comment: I can apply the jQuery solution to the view's page. It should be okay.

Comment: I almost got it, I have one question left: are there other persons or just this 5. because making an "1 and 2" or "2 and 3".. query is really difficult.

Comment: Currently there are only 5 people, but it could expand in the future.

Comment: so there are no other people in this list, I'm asking because maybe we only need to count the people and can leave the and/or condition away?

Comment: So this list is the Meetings list. We are using this list on two pages, a one-on-one page and a team page. Any meetings that only have two people, will show up on the a user's one-on-one page. On the team page, it should show all the meetings where there's more than 2 people in the Meeting With people field.